# How to get boolean value using $resource of AngularJS and spring rest controller

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, angular-resource, ngresource

Trying to send get boolean value from spring restcontroller using $resource service of angular js ,but getting nothing in response of $resource.get.Is there anythingextra i need to add on my client side or server side for getting boolean resource. Below is my code for rest controller and $resource
 Rest controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value="validate/company/{companyName}",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces={"application/json"})
public Boolean validateCouponCode(@PathVariable("companyName") String companyName){
    return companyService.exists(companyName, Column.SITE_NAME);

}
```

$resourse of Angular js -

```
function validateCompanyFn(companyName)  
    return $resource("admin/rest/company/validate/company/:companyName")
    .get({companyName:companyName}).$promise
}
```

What i am doing wrong?
please suggest, if there is another way of getting boolean response using $resource, and without using any extra object on server side

Comment: When you make a request to the resource directly (curl, postman, etc). Do you get a response?

Comment: There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer` as `$promise` already **is** a promise.

Comment: @tah tatsumoto , yes getting correct response when hitting the url on chrome browser directlr

Answer (score 5):

### $resource does not return booleans

The `$resource.get` method only returns *object references*, not booleans.

It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an *empty reference* (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

Under the hood, the `$resource` service uses [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to populate the object.

> ### angular.copy
>
> Creates a deep copy of source, **which should be an object or an array.**
>
> - If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.
>
> [— AngularJS angular.copy API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

**Since a boolean has no elements/properties, nothing is copied.**

To return a boolean, use the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
//USE $http service
function getSubCategoryIdNameFn(catId){
    var url = "admin/rest/subcategory-id-name/" + catId;
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

---

There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer` as `$promise` already **is** a promise. Simply **return the `$promise`**

```
//SIMPLIFY
function getSubCategoryIdNameFn(catId){
    //var deferred = $q.defer();
    //vvvv RETURN the $promise
    return $resource("admin/rest/subcategory-id-name/:catId",{catId:"@catId"})
      .query({catId:catId})
      .$promise
    //.then(function(response){
    //    deferred.resolve(response);
    //},function(error){
    //    deferred.reject(error);
    //});
    //return deferred.promise;
}
```